# Help proving $Pr(\mathcal{X})= \phi_1(X,Z)\phi_2(Y,Z)$ if $ P \models (X \perp Y | Z)$ and $\mathcal{X}=X \cup Y \cup Z$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I was trying to prove the following:

> if $X,Y,Z$ were three disjoint subsets of variables such that
>   $\mathcal{X}=X \cup Y \cup Z$, Prove that $ P \models (X \perp Y \mid
> Z)$ if and only if we can write P in the form:
>
> $$P(\mathcal{X})= \phi_1(X,Z)\phi_2(Y,Z)$$

I was a little stuck but was unsure if I it was because I didn't know how to do the proof or if I got confused about the statement of the question.

What does the statement "$X,Y,Z$ were three disjoint subsets" mean? I understand it as $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, $X \cap Z = \emptyset$, $Y \cap Z = \emptyset$ and $X \cap Y \cap Z = \emptyset$.

Which makes my initial equations move towards things that don't make sense or are hard to move on. This is what I have so far:

$P(\mathcal{X}) = P(X \cup Y \cup Z)$
$P(X \cup Y \cup Z) = P(X) + P(Y) + P(Z) - P(X,Y) - P(Y,Z) - P(X,Z) + P(X,Y,Z)$

Using the info given:

$P(X \cup Y \cup Z) = P(X) + P(Y) + P(Z)$

Which gets me stuck. Thus, I am assuming that interpretation was wrong and instead I moved towards a different direction that didn't yield to much either...

$P(X \cup Y \cup Z) = P(X) + P(Y) + P(Z) - P(X,Y) - P(Y,Z) - P(X,Z) + P(X,Y,Z)$
$P(X \cup Y \cup Z) = P(X) + P(Y) + P(Z) - P(X|Y)P(Y) - P(Z)P(Y|Z) - P(Z)P(X|Z) + P(Z)P(X|Z)P(Y,Z)$

which then I try to factorize but I can't figure out how.

Some hints and clarification before stating the solution in your answer would be better (that way I can first have a clarification and try the proof again before reading the actual solution).

Thanks!

---

This is self study, just for fun, for me :) No class no homework no nothing like that.

Answer (score 2):

The puzzlement comes in great part from some horrendous abuses of notations.

The setting seems to be that one considers some disjoint sets $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ of random variables and the collection $\mathcal X$ which is the (disjoint) union of these three sets of random variables.

Then the hypothesis is that the random variables in $X$ are jointly independent of the random variables in $Y$ conditionally on the random variables in $Z$.

The conclusion one is asked to prove (in the discrete setting, to simplify the formulas) is that for every random variables $(X_i)$ in $X$, every random variables $(Y_j)$ in $Y$ and every random variables $(Z_k)$ in $Z$, the joint distribution of $((X_i),(Y_j),(Z_k))$ can be written as follows: $$P((X_i)=(x_i),(Y_j)=(y_j),(Z_k)=(z_k))=\phi_1((x_i),(z_k))\cdot\phi_2((y_j),(z_k)),$$ for some functions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ and for every collections of (deterministic) values $(x_i)$, $(y_j)$, $(z_k)$.

Comment: sorry if this is really obvious but, I am still confused what is suppose to be proved. What I understand is that given all variable in $Z$, then one should be able to write the union probability as a product of two functions, one a function of $X,Z$ and another as a function of $Y, Z$. Also, could you clarify to me what notation is being abused and how? That might be why I am getting confused. Also, if you already know the answer, is it suppose to be "easy"?

Comment: You are supposed to write down the identity defining conditional independence that you know, and to (try to) transform it into the identity in my answer.

Comment: There is no **union** here, there never was, just write down the definitions.

Comment: I don't mean this question to be annoying, but I just don't understand why you would say that there is no union here if the core of the question states to find an expression for $P(\mathcal{X})$, where $\mathcal{X} = X \cup Y \cup Z$ is a union. I genuinely trying to understand why what you wrote is suppose to be what I should be looking for. (Also, the abuse of notation came from a book, not myself, so if the question is weird, I am not be blamed, I am just trying to understand what its saying)

Comment: Except that $\mathcal X$ is not a union of events but the collection union of the collections $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. Please read my post carefully.

Comment: Is the first direction of the answer just $P(\mathcal{X}) = P(X,Y \mid Z) P(Z) = P(X \mid Z) P(Y \mid Z) P(Z)$ where $\phi_1(X,Z) = P(X \mid Z)$ and $\phi_2(Y,Z) = P(Y|Z)P(Z)$? Not sure what the other direction of the proof is since its a iff...